# How to do you work with a matrix in large model assembly 8086?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I have a C program that calls a procedure from assembly, I'm working with the large model, I don't understand how to access my matrix that I'm sending from C.
After I call the assembly procedure I do the following,
C code:

```
extern long int f1(long int *arr_ptr[]);
void main()
{
  long int arr1[4]= {113891, 319762, 987431, 765437}; 
  long int arr2[4]= {567434, 988885, 654329, 999990}; 
  long int arr3[4]= {123456, 999999, 888880, 498766}; 
  long int *arr_ptr[3];
  arr_ptr[0] = arr1;
  arr_ptr[1] = arr2;
  arr_ptr[2] = arr3;
  f1(arr_ptr);}
```

Assembly code:

```
PUBLIC _f1
    _f1 PROC FAR
    .386
    PUSH BP
    MOV BP,SP
    PUSH BP
    PUSH ES
    PUSH DI


    MOV DI,[BP+6];take the offset
    MOV ES,[BP+8];take the segment

    MOV EDX,DWORD PTR [ES:DI];store the first value at row 1 and col 1
    POP DI
    POP ES
    POP BP
    RET
    _f1 ENDP

END
```

Comment: look at the disassembly of the C program to see where it is placing things and pick the data up there.

Comment: I'm using turbo C ,mind telling me how i could do that?.And are you saying that these MOV commands are correct but the problem is somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MOV DX,[BX]` is the same as `MOV DX,[DS:BX]`.  In other words, it is assuming that the matrix values are in `DS:`.

But if the matrix arrived in a `FAR` pointer, the segment of which was loaded in `ES:`, then the chances that the matrix values are in `DS:` are slim.

So, one of the following is true:

- Either in `[ES:DI]` you will find the segment:address of the first row, or
- In `[ES:DI]` you will find the first value of the first row rather than the address of the first row.

In order to tell, you should show us how the matrix is defined in C.

EDIT

So, you are loading `ES:DI` with the address of `arr_ptr`.  Then you need to obtain the address of `arr1`.  For that, you will need the following:

```
MOV AX, [ES:DI]
MOV DI, [ES:DI + 2]
MOV ES, AX
```

then, you can obtain the value of `arr1[0]` with `MOV EDX,DWORD PTR [ES:DI]`.

Comment: `  long int arr1[4]= {113891, 319762, 987431, 765437}; 
  long int arr2[4]= {567434, 988885, 654329, 999990}; 
  long int arr3[4]= {123456, 999999, 888880, 498766}; 
  long int *arr_ptr[3];
  arr_ptr[0] = arr1;
  arr_ptr[1] = arr2;
  arr_ptr[2] = arr3;`

Comment: please put that in the question and format it properly.

Comment: I'm trying to post my C code and assembly but i keep getting an error that its not properly formatted

Comment: @MikeNakis - for Microsoft assembler, the syntax is `mov ax,es:[bx]` and `mov dx,es:[bx+2]` or `mov ax,es:2[bx]` . I deleted my prior comment.